# How to scale an image for fill pattern without displaying the original image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have come up with something that suits my needs based on the threads on this subject.
It turns out that in order to scale an image for pattern fill you need 2 canvases. The first canvas creates the scaled image which is used in the second canvas. All of the examples I found display both canvases, but I only want to display the second canvas
Snip:

```
  var c = document.getElementById("DrawQuote");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(10, 10, c.width, c.height);
```

Then ctx context is used to draw some rectangles and polygons, I omitted the code
Then I need to draw a rectangle with scaled image pattern
Snip:

```
  // create the canvas with scaled image
  var imgtoscale = new Image();
  imgtoscale.src = "blah.jpg";
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById("TempCanvas");
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  canvas1.width = imgtoscale.width / Scale / 4;
  canvas1.height = imgtoscale.height / Scale / 4;
  ctx1.drawImage(imgtoscale, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);

  // draw a rectangle filled with the scaled image from above
  // ctx is my main canvas, the one I want to display
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(canvas1, "repeat");
  ctx.fillRect(400, 40, 300, 300);
```

2 images are displayed:
  1-the scaled image to the TempCanvas element
  2-the rectangle with scaled fill pattern to the DrawQuote element

But I only want to display the DrawQuote element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what "threads" you saw, but I guess they were displaying the second canvas only to make clear what happens, however, you really don't need to append that second canvas in the document, it can stay "offscreen":

```js
// the only one visible
var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var Scale = 2;
var imgtoscale = new Image();
imgtoscale.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Woodward_Iowa_Tornado_Damage.JPG/1024px-Woodward_Iowa_Tornado_Damage.JPG";
imgtoscale.onload = function() {

  // we create a new canvas element
  var canvas1 = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext( '2d' );
  canvas1.width = imgtoscale.width / Scale / 4;
  canvas1.height = imgtoscale.height / Scale / 4;
  ctx1.drawImage( imgtoscale, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height );

  // draw a rectangle filled with the scaled image from above
  // ctx is my main canvas, the one I want to display
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern( canvas1, 'repeat' );
  ctx.fillRect( 100, 100, 300, 300 );
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Now note that what these threads missed is that the `fillStyle` is dependent on the current transformation matrix of the context, so you don't even need a second canvas to do what you want:

First declare the path you wish to fill at normal scale, then set the context scale to what you want, and finally fill.

```js
// the only canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var Scale = 2;
var imgtoscale = new Image();
imgtoscale.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Woodward_Iowa_Tornado_Damage.JPG/1024px-Woodward_Iowa_Tornado_Damage.JPG";
imgtoscale.onload = function() {
  // create the CanvasPattern directly from the <img>
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern( imgtoscale, 'repeat' );
  // declare your path to fill
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect( 100, 100, 300, 300 );
  // change the scaling (of the fillStyle)
  ctx.scale( 1 / Scale / 4, 1 / Scale / 4 );
  ctx.fill();
  // reset back to default?
  ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answers!  
This was one of the my sources for the 2 canvas approach, but there were others on stackoverflow:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331036/how-to-scale-an-image-for-fill-pattern-without-displaying-the-original-image  
I assumed from the examples I found that there would not be a `.scale` method, but this is a nice surprise  :-)  My bad for not checking the all the methods for HTML canvas.  
In your second example, I am curious about your use of `.beginPath`, I though this was only necessary for drawing a polygon.

Comment: Yes beginPath is only necessary for drawing polygons, which I'm doing with `.rect()` just after. Strictly speaking in this exact case that wouldn't be needed since it's the first sub-path to be declared, but I believe it's better to be explicit, and at least it causes no harm.